# Plotting data that lands on the axis

Tags: plotting

I have a data point that lands right on the Y axis, which corresponds to the index of refraction of some sample.  the x axis is the mole fraction of chloroform of my samples.

How do I get the first data point to look sensible (ie, not directly on the axis). I think it looks funny like this.

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
moleFraction[molesA_, molesB_] = molesA/(molesA + molesB);
molesChloroform = {0.125, 0.100, 0.0625, 0.0375, 0};
molesAcetone = {0, 0.027, 0.068, 0.0952, 0.136};
molefrac = moleFraction[molesChloroform, molesAcetone];
calibrationIndexOfRefraction = {1.440, 1.421, 1.395, 1.380, 1.351};
errorBars = {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
newList = Partition[Riffle[molefrac, calibrationIndexOfRefraction], 2];
test = Thread[{newList, ErrorBar[errorBars[[1]], 0]}]
ErrorListPlot[test, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {1.30, 1.45}}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: My Plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using a Frame you do not need Axes at all.  You could use:

```
ErrorListPlot[test, PlotRange -> {{-0.15, 1.2}, {1.30, 1.45}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None]
```

Though longer you could also use `PlotRangePadding` if you wish not to change PlotRange:

```
ErrorListPlot[test,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {1.30, 1.45}},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> None, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0.15, 0}, {0, 0}}
]
```

[image]

If you actually need axis lines you can use `AxesOrigin`:

```
ErrorListPlot[test,
 PlotRange -> {{-0.15, 1.2}, {1.30, 1.45}},
 AxesOrigin -> {-0.15, 1.3}
]
```

[image]